# SQL Server Database Connectivity Issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server instance from C#.

Here is my connection string, I am getting an exception

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

when I tried executing this code:

```
constr = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

My local datasource is `ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS`, I have tried with below string too, here I am getting compile time error as

> Unrecogonized Esscape Sequence

Code:

```
constr = "Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

Please help me with this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use "/" instead of "\", Regards,

Comment: In C#, put an "@" in front of a string that contains slashes, so they're not interpreted as escape characters (like const = @"ELCOT-PC\SQLExpress";), or double the slashes (like "const = "ELCOT-PC\\SQLExpress") to properly escape them.

Comment: I tried with all the options you gave but I am getting exception "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
constr="Data Source=ELCOT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

OR use Varbatim

```
constr=@"Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

### UPDATE

Since the above will fix your connection string, Now you need to make sure you are connecting to `Named Instance` of sql server or `Default Instance`.

The rule is when you are trying to connect to a Default Instance you only use the `MachineName` in your Data Source property of your connection string.

Whereas if you are trying to connect to a `Named Instance` of Sql Server on a server/machine you will have to use the `ServerName\InstanceName` to connect to sql server.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use "/" instead of "\", or add @ (verbatim) in front of the string as shown below:

```
constr=@"Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am getting run time exception as "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network name cannot be found"

Answer (score 2):

Change data source to server if you are trying to connect to a named instance

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

For the second case you need to escape the `\`. You can use @ to do the escaping:

```
constr=@"Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 1):

use "/" instead of "\", or add @ (verbatim)

```
constr="Data Source=ELCOT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

or

```
constr=@"Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```

or

```
constr=@"Data Source=ELCOT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bookstall;Integrated Security=True";
```